# Converting linear points of a sound wave into logarithmic ones

Tags: logarithms

I have a graph of a sound wave in a linear display :

[image]

I need to get a graph of the sound wave in logarithmic form, namely :

[image]

The wave values are displayed in symmetrical mode. Here's what the wave display will look like without symmetric mode:

[image]

The boundaries of this graph are between **0** and **127**.

My task is to convert the received linear points (from **0** to **127**) into logarithmic points (also from **0** to **127**).

What formula should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ be a start point and $(x_2,y_2)=(127,127)$ be a end point. Moreover let $c>1$ be a logarithm base. We have to find linear function $$h(x)=ax+b\quad\quad (1)$$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
h(0)=1\\
h(127)=c^{127}
\end{cases}\quad\quad (2)
$$
then final formula (or function) will be:
$$ f(x)=\log_c h(x)$$
becouse $f(0)=\log_c h(0)=\log_c 1=0$ and $f(127)=\log_c h(127)=\log_c c^{127}=127$.
Lets find now $a$ and $b$ in (1) using conditions from (2):
$$\begin{cases}
h(0)=1\\
h(127)=c^{127}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
a\cdot 0 + b = 1\\
a\cdot 127 + b=c^{127}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
b = 1\\
a =\frac{c^{127}-1}{127}
\end{cases},
$$
so $h(x)=ax+b=\frac{c^{127}-1}{127}x + 1$ and thus your formula is:
$$
f(x)=\log_c\left(\frac{c^{127}-1}{127}x + 1\right) \quad\quad (3)
$$
I assume, that you will use it to processing sound data on computer, whereas $c^{127}$ is huge number. We can (3) write also as:
$$
f(x)=\log_c\left(\frac{c^{y_2}-1}{y_1}x + 1\right)
$$ and now if you first get formula for e.g. $y_2=30$ and then miltiple this logarithm by $\frac{127}{y_2}$ then the result will be similar, but with smaller numbers, i.e.:
$$
f(x)=\frac{127}{30}\cdot\log_c\left(\frac{c^{30}-1}{127}x + 1\right)
$$
Also choice of $c$ will has impact on final result and calculation speed, I supose.